# Pandas indexing .loc error "'the label [2013_09_09] is not in the [index]'"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas pivot table shown as below.

> ```
>    TIME       　　00:00:00   00:30:00   01:00:00    01:30:00    02:00:00
> DAY CUSTOMER_ID
> 　　　　10006414    　0.056     0.052        0.050       0.051       0.051  
> 2013-　 10006486 　　 0.081     0.132  　　　0.037    　　0.048 　　　0.066
> 09-09   10006492　　　0.063 　　0.073        0.048       0.048       0.064
> ```

I generated the above pivot table by the code below.

> selcust_data = pd.pivot_table(sel_data, values='TOTAL_SUPPLY_KWH', index=['DAY','CUSTOMER_ID'], columns=['TIME'])
>   selcust_data=selcust_data.dropna()

Then I tried to access rows of the table with index.

> selcust_data.loc['2013_09_09']

Obviously, '2013_09_09' should be a valid label in the index range. Yet the following error always appears.
KeyError: 'the label [2013_09_09] is not in the [index]'

I cannot figure out the root cause today. Hope anyone could help. Thanks!

Comment: `selcust_data.loc['2013-09-09']` You used underscores instead of hyphens.

Comment: Looking at your table, the index is `'2013-09-09'`, not `'2013_09_09'. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks COLDSPEED and AMC for the answer. However, I tried hyphens instead of underscores, and the same error still showed up.    KeyError: 'the label [2013-09-09] is not in the [index]'

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that the data type was datetime.date, so I should use datetime.date(2013,9,9) instead of '2013_09_09'.